# Intellij API. Saving User Data to PsiElement

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin, intellij-platform-psi

Saving User Data to PsiElement

Hello. I have got a question.

We need to solve the following problem. Save User Data to PsiElement. So that they are saved when parsing a file. For example, when calling the function `FileContentUtil.reparseFiles(PsiLanguageInjectionHost, List, Boolean)`. Looking for answers. It is recommended to use `CachedValueManager` and `CachedValue`. How to use them correctly in my case?

Comment: The best place for API questions would be the dev forum at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development.